# How to store a tree in database

Tags: git, mongodb, database

I am trying to store a github like commit / branch tree in the mongodb. Each of the commit node would have a unified identifier (It is not actual github so I can't use any git APIs unfortunately)

I am not sure about what is the best way to do this. And what would be the best structure about the database.

The current thoughts I have is:

1. Store as an array (could be efficient but need more works)
2. Store as an tree (likely not very efficient since commit would be more than branches)

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Serialized JSON would be my suggestion.

Comment: Will "history rewrites" be supported as in git?